# How to create variables for multiple classes objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I have a load of variables that I want to be accessed from multiple classes in objective-c.

For example I have a list of colours. Ideally I would just have a `Colours.h` file and do something like this:

```
@interface Colours : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSColor* black = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.13 green:0.13 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];
@property (readonly) NSColor* white = [NSColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];
@property (readonly) NSColor* red = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.74 green:0.13 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];
@property (readonly) NSColor* grey = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.43 green:0.43 blue:0.43 alpha:1.0];
@property (readonly) NSColor* boarder = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0];
@property (readonly) NSColor* offwhite = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.96 green:0.96 blue:0.96 alpha:1.0];
@end
```

and then import the `Colours.h` in each of my classes and call `Colours.boarder` but this is not possible.

So should I do something like this with a `.m`?

```
#import "Colours.h"

@implementation Colours
-(id)init{
    _black = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.13 green:0.13 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];
    _white = [NSColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];
    _red = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.74 green:0.13 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];
    _grey = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.43 green:0.43 blue:0.43 alpha:1.0];
    _boarder = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0];
    _offwhite = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.96 green:0.96 blue:0.96 alpha:1.0];
}
@end
```

This seems a little overkill as I would then need to `init` the class?

I am also worried that I have class A which imports class B and B imports class C and all three classes need the colours. Is it bad to use the same `#import` for each class or is there a more efficient way to do this?

---

## another technique?

`.h`

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface Colours: NSObject
+(NSColor *)black;
+(NSColor *)white;
+(NSColor *)red;
+(NSColor *)grey;
+(NSColor *)boarder;
+(NSColor *)offwhite;
@end
```

`.m`

```
@implementation Colours
+(NSColor *)black{
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:0.13 green:0.13 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];
}

+(NSColor *)white{
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];
}

+(NSColor *)red{
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:0.74 green:0.13 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];
}

+(NSColor *)grey{
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:0.43 green:0.43 blue:0.43 alpha:1.0];
}

+(NSColor *)boarder{
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0];
}

+(NSColor *)offwhite{
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:0.96 green:0.96 blue:0.96 alpha:1.0];
}
@end
```

Comment: Why not using an Extension, with `+(NSColor *)myCustomBlackColor` instead?

Comment: do you mean like my new edit?

Comment: and then I can call `[Colours red];` ?

Comment: @Larme Too much Swift. You mean category, not extension. :)

Comment: @rmaddy Indeed, I meant "Category", that's why I also named `myCustomBlackColor` instead of `black` because of conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer Objective-C compilers support class level properties. If you look at the documentation for `NSColor` you will see that this is how all of the predefined colors are declared.

Colours.h:

```
@interface Colours : NSObject

@property (class, readonly) NSColor* black;
@property (class, readonly) NSColor* white;

@end
```

Colours.m:

```
@implementation Colours

+ (NSColor *)black {
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:0.13 green:0.13 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];
}

+ (NSColor *)white {
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

Import `Colours.h` where needed and then do:

```
NSColor *myColor = Colours.black;
```

Another option is to add a category to `NSColor`. This is nearly the same as what I show above but instead of declaring a class named `Colours`, you declare a category on `NSColor`. The important thing here is that your color names would need to be unique so you couldn't use `blackColor` or `whiteColor` since they already exist on `NSColor`.

NSColor+Mine.h:

```
@interface NSColor (Mine)

@property (class, readonly) NSColor* myBlack;
@property (class, readonly) NSColor* myWhite;

@end
```

NSColor+Mine.m:

```
@implementation NSColor (Mine)

+ (NSColor *)myBlack {
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:0.13 green:0.13 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];
}

+ (NSColor *)myWhite {
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

Import `NSColor+Mine.h` where needed and then do:

```
NSColor *myColor = NSColor.myBlack;
```